# require_once(): Failed opening required > '/wp-load.php'

Tags: php, wordpress, path, include, require

I have a file, mail.php - it's in the `public_html/scripts/` directory.

I have an ajax javascript function that calls it:

```
<script>
function sendEmail() {
  var variable1 = 'hello'; // Get the value from the input box
  var variable2 = 'world'; // Get the value from the input box

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/scripts/mail.php', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
      // Request completed successfully
      console.log('Email sent successfully!');
    }
  };
  xhr.send('variable1=' + encodeURIComponent(variable1) + '&variable2=' + encodeURIComponent(variable2));
}
    sendEmail();
 </script>
```

The file `mail.php` has the following:

```
<?php
require_once('/wp-load.php'); // Load the WordPress core file to access WordPress functions
```

When looking in Developer Tools (Chrome), the Response to mail.php in the Network tab is:

> **Fatal error**:  require_once(): Failed opening required
> '/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php74/pear') in
> **/home/customer/www/website.com/public_html/scripts/mail.php** on
> line **2**

I've tried with just: require_once('../wp-load.php') and require_once('../../wp-load.php')

But the error remains.

Is this a permissions issue (should my scripts directory be in wp-content for example), or is there anything else obvious wrong with my code?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: this / at the really beginning means it is absolute path. Try without it. or add what is needed for a full absolute path.

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure what the absolute path is - it's a hosted site - even if I put in the full https://...../scripts/mail.php - it gives the same error. Thanks

Comment: php is executed server-side, the url is not relevant. you have to find the wp-loap.php file on the server itself, most probably at the root of your wordpress site. the absolute path will be something looking like "/home/customer/www/website.com/public_html/scripts/mail.php"

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a dot at the beginning of the file name:

```
<?php
require_once('./wp-load.php'); // Load the WordPress core file to access WordPress functions
```

And check if the wp-load.php is in the same folder of your script.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get the same error: <b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once(): Failed opening required './wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php74/pear') - the mail.php script is in a directory: scripts - which is in the public_html folder. So it's not in the same folder, but the next folder back.

Comment: can you put here the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wp_smtp_mail plugin, and referencing that in my PHP - but the error was showing as not being able to load wp-load.php

When I send using wp_mail (default WP mail function), it works without the error.

It seems the error was not with wp-load.php, although that's where developer tools network tab, suggested it was.

So, not using the plugin, and using the default mail, has solved this problem, if not the reason for the error.